# Express session - Can admin remove other user session?

Tags: express, session

I got a question, how can admin want to force logout other users?

Such as user data is stored on database, admin updated the DB to make user account status become disabled, but the status in user session is still enabled. Hence that the user is still logged in and admin can't force logout the user.

Comment: You will have to remove the live session object from express-session if you want the user to be logged out.  How exactly you do that depends upon you you're using express-session.  By default, it uses a memory store and you'd have to find their session in that memory store and remove it.  Or, you can configure it to use your database for storage and then you can remove the session object from your database.  Using express-session directly, you'll want to call [`store.destroy(sid, callback)`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#storedestroysid-callback).

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get the other user sid by user ID/ name?

Comment: The sid is available at either `req.sessionID` or `req.session.id` during an http request.  So, you have to somehow associate either sessions with users or session ids with users so you can get from the user to the current sessionid for that user.